# Permanent Access Token in OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

Is it possible to get a permanent access token using OAuth2?  I want to use Box to download files during an installation.  The installation grabs all of the files in a particular folder.  I have a box account set up as the owner of the folder and in API v1 I can get a permanent auth_token to reuse in my executable.  But it appears that with OAuth2 I can only get a 1 hour access token and a refresh token.  But because the end user does not actually have access to Box, and the application is a desktop application, they can't authenticate on the fly if a token has expired.  I know there are other solutions out there, but the V1 api let me do this and I was hoping to not lose this functionality when V1 is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Box's implementation of OAuth2 does not generate permanent tokens.  However, just as in the V1 API, you can create a link for a file you upload that is accessible to non-Box users.  You have to set the shared access to "open" in the UI, or via API the json.

There's a [section in the docs](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) that explain how to do it.  You essentially pass a PUT to the /files/ endpoint with a small JSON body like this:

```
{"shared_link": {"access": "open"}}
```

You will get back a json file body, with a shared_link section that is complete.  Something like this:

```
"shared_link": {
    "url": "https://www.box.com/s/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul",
    "download_url": "https://www.box.com/shared/static/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul.jpeg",
    "vanity_url": null,
    "is_password_enabled": false,
    "unshared_at": null,
    "download_count": 0,
    "preview_count": 0,
    "access": "open",
    "permissions": {
        "can_download": true,
        "can_preview": true
    }
```

Comment: All other cloud provider I have experience with provide a static refresh token (Google Drive, SkyDrive for example). May not be according to spec, but makes it much easier to maintain it properly.

Say I want to save the updated refreshtoken after each usage of it - that's fine, but what if there is some malfunction or the app gets terminated for some reason before that happens (on a mobile device for example). Then I will have to request, that the user redo the authentication flow all over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use refresh token to get a new access token that lasts another hour, and a new refresh token.

So your desktop application may need to connect to internet *securely* to read/write

- access token
- access token expiry date
- refresh token
- refresh token expiry date**

**Each refresh token is only valid for 14 days. Was hoping that Box remove the expiry feature.

Alternatively, put your files on a publicly accessible location as per original suggestion.